# How to process null value inside json string using lua?

Tags: json, lua

I am using lua in asterisk pbx. I encounter following problem while processing json string.

**json "null" value converted to function type in lua. why?**

how to handle this scenario? because i am expecting nil because no value means null in json and nil means nothing in lua.

```
local json = require( "json" )
local inspect = require("inspect")
local myjson_str='{"Sms":{"key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","to":"{caller}","senderid":null,"type":"Simple","content":"Your request has been accepted in Previous Miss call. We get back to you very soon."}}'

local myjson_table = json.decode(myjson_str)
print(type(myjson_table["Sms"]["senderid"]))
print(myjson_table)
print(inspect(myjson_table))
print(json.encode(myjson_table))
```

out put for above is

```
function
table: 0xf5e770
{
  Sms = {
    content = "Your request has been accepted in Previous Miss call. We get back to you very soon.",
    key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    senderid = <function 1>,
    to = "{caller}",
    type = "Simple"
  }
}
{"Sms":{"type":"Simple","key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","senderid":null,"content":"Your request has been accepted in Previous Miss call. We get back to you very soon.","to":"{caller}"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to specific library to decide how to represent `null` value.
Using `nil` has its own problem because its not possible find either 
original JSON has key with null value or there no such key at all.
So some libraries just return some unique value. Some provide 
a way to pass this value like `json.deconde(str, NULL_VALUE)`.
So answer is just read the doc/source of library you use.
Most likely it provide something like `json.null` value to check 
either value is null. But function is really strange choice because
they have some undetermined rules of uniqueness.
Or try another library.

Comment: json.util.null is the function i found finally. I manage to process same. Your point is correct it depend on what library/language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @moteus is right:

> It is up to specific library to decide how to represent null value

If you're using the [JSON library by Jeffrey Friedl](http://regex.info/blog/lua/json) the solution is to use a placeholder instead of `null` and serializing the table structure to a json string using designated encode options:

```lua
-- define a placeholder
NullPlaceholder = "\0"

-- use it in an internal table
tableStructure = {}
tableStructure['someNullValue'] = NullPlaceholder

-- pass the placeholder to the encode methode
encode_options = { null = NullPlaceholder }
jsonString = JSON:encode(tableStructure, nil, encode_options)
```

which leads to

```
{"someNullValue": null}
```